# In asp.net Paytm Integration

Tags: asp.net

I have successfully verify the checksum but it print the below msg , not able to understand what to do after this.

Below code snippet running well and Print “Checksum Matched”;

```
if (CheckSum.verifyCheckSum(merchantKey, parameters, paytmChecksum))
{
    Response.Write(“Checksum Matched”);
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue here? `it print the below msg` which message ? Shouldn't it be displayed if the checksum matches?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.